# django apache css error 500

Tags: django, apache, django-wsgi

I recently started a site using django mingus, but the problem is that the css are not showing, Im getting a server internal error 500 when serving the media files.

Im using apache, mod_wsgi.

https://gist.github.com/f25d5ecdab235d4da69b <-- settings.py
https://gist.github.com/d838c1923729afddf24a <-- apache site
https://gist.github.com/d1e11e937e5910e839ee <-- django.wsgi file

Im getting this in the logs

190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:21:46 +0000] "GET /static/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 9751
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4079
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4078
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:21 +0000] "GET /static/css/pygments.css HTTP/1.1" 500 9799
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:21 +0000] "GET /static/css/themes/basic.css HTTP/1.1" 500 9801
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:21 +0000] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 500 9790
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:21 +0000] "GET /static/css/prettify.css HTTP/1.1" 500 9792
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:21 +0000] "GET /static/css/960.css HTTP/1.1" 500 9797
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:22 +0000] "GET /static/js/prettify.js HTTP/1.1" 500 9833
190.158.255.93 - - [19/Feb/2011:20:23:22 +0000] "GET /static/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 9738

Any more information you might need let me know... what might be wrong here?

Thank you all.

Comment: There should be an `error.log` file that gives you more info

Comment: Hi, actually the apache error.log is not showing anything. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an Alias to your static folder in your apache conf (https://gist.github.com/d838c1923729afddf24a)  so that your static files get delivered by apache and not mod_wsgi

like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIDaemonProcess maumercado user=maumercado group=maumercado processes=1 threads=10 python-path=/home/maumercado/venvs/maublog/lib/python2.6/site-packages
ServerName www.maumercado.com
ServerAdmin admin@maumercado.com

Alias /static/  /path/to/folder/static/

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/maumercado/code/django/maublog/mingus/deploy/maublog.wsgi
WSGIProcessGroup maumercado

<Directory "/home/maumercado/code/django/maublog/mingus/deploy/">
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/maublog/apache_error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/maublog/apache_access.log common
ServerSignature On
```